# gtk custom spin button

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I want to make a gtk SpinButton, but for inputting dates.

1. Is there an easier way to input dates into GTK?
2. If not, how can I create a SpinButton look-alike, but whose output is text representing dates instead of integers? Ideally I'd re-use the arrows, the clicks, the integration with the adjustment, etc. I really just need the output to look different, as I can even represent dates as integers.

Answer (score 3):

The calendar is a bit large, but you can find code putting it in a popup. Personally I use a regular text entry and parse the date.

As for SpinButton, it is based on a text entry, so you might be able to modify its display only by fiddling with inherited signals and returning False. See also the update-policy and numeric properties.

Comment: This is exactly my answer, especially the first paragraph.  Use a GtkCalendar, unless it feels inconvenient, in which case just parse text dates.  SpinButtons are usually unpleasant to use anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could use [`GtkCalendar`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkCalendar.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote such a thing for myself:

https://github.com/ilius/starcal/blob/master/scal3/ui_gtk/mywidgets/multi_spin/date.py

Comment: Both of these links are dead. Is this code available somewhere?

Comment: Downvote for broken links. *IF* you post link- only answers, make sure either the link is correct or move the content into the post.

Comment: I replaced the links