# gtk create small up + down buttons as in a gtk.SpinButton

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404825/gtk-custom-spin-button), but more specific: how can I create tiny button widgets like in a `gtk.SpinButton`?

Answer (score 0):

This is also my question for many monthes.
You can use gtk.Arrow, unless that's not exactly the same as SpinButton.